# When should a function be inlined (performance-wise)?

Tags: performance, optimization, f#, inline

I've witnessed posts in SO mentioning inlining has made their software run significantly faster <sup>[[example]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086580/)</sup>.
It made me wonder, when should I make a function inlined *for performance*?

Also, would the same guidelines for C++ inlining apply?

**Note:**
I'm not asking when (obviously when needed), or why, I'm asking that if I happen to reach a bottleneck, when would inlining could be helpful?

Comment: Never optimise anything in any way until (1) you have a performance problem AND (2) you have hard evidence that you are optimising the right things.

Comment: In modern C++, inlining has everything to with linkage and nothing to do with performance, so any comparisons to C++ are specious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, the `inline` keyword is mainly useful in two situations:

- It lets you write [generic numeric code](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-generic-numeric.aspx/) which would not be possible without `inline`. So in this case, you need inlining regardless of the performance concerns.
- I think that generic comparison (see [also this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104221/why-is-this-f-code-so-slow)) is the main use case where `inline` significantly improves performance (because the inlined code can be specialized for the current type rather than using generic comparison).

In all other cases, adding `inline` might make code a little bit faster, but probably won't have significant effect. So I would only use it when you are actually optimizing some bottleneck.

Comment: There's also another option, [like hacking typeclasses onto F#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8439395/1180426) :) Although I wish there was *some* kind of mechanism for that, I actually wouldn't mind Scala's `implicit`s.

Answer (score 0):

> if I happen to reach a bottleneck, when would inlining could be helpful?

[*This is the method I use*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771) to look for speedups.

If I see that the program counter is in the process of entering or leaving a method X or several methods similar to X on a significant fraction of samples, then it could be worthwhile to inline them.

This will only happen on very short methods that don't perform further calls within them.

Comment: When writing code in F#, you also have a very powerful REPL available. So you can use the `#time` directive and measure the performance of functions really easily (provided that your project is organized in a way that makes it possible to load it into F# interactive).

Comment: @Tomas: I'm sure you can. I'm trying not to start flaming about how to do performance tuning, 'cause I think I know how :)  Suffice it to say - I think you need percent wall time, not just "time", and it's more productive to take a small number of whole-program, or at least stack, snapshots. (Accuracy of timing is not important, in spite of common wisdom.) Measurements are fine for seeing if what you fixed made a difference - they're not so good for telling you what you need to fix.

Comment: @Tomas: If I could build an ideal profiler, it would look like this: It would sample at least the stack on wall-time (so as not to miss IO), and possibly data variables as well. Then it would apply artificial intelligence (which I studied) to the samples, looking for arbitrary commonalities in the context of understanding the program. If commonality X is evident on fraction F of samples, that's roughly what it costs. Well, AI is still a future, but the next best thing is between our ears, so that's what I use. Some say "don't you need a large number of samples?" Answer: no, no, and no.